# How to get an element of an object from a linkedlist using streams in Java

Tags: java, java-stream

Consider a class ABC

```
class ABC{
  int id;
  String text;
  getter & setter methods..
}
```

A list of instances of ABC is collected in a linked list.

```
Linkedlist<ABC>
```

Now, I have an input int n. Based on the input n, I need to check list of ABC instances where I can get a match `(n == d)`

Based on the match, I will have to retrieve the corresponding String text from the same instance of ABC.

For example:

```
Linkedlist<ABC> list = new Linkedlist<>();
list.add(new ABC(1,"Eagle");
list.add(new ABC(2,"Tiger");
list.add(new ABC(3,"Rabbit");
```

if the input n = 3,
then I need to get the below result:
"Rabbit"

I tried to use streams as below:

```
list.stream().filter(p -> p.getId() == n).map(ABC:: getText);
```

But I want only String as an answer from the above line.

Comment: .findFirst() may be what you're looking for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use

- `findFirst` to get one `ABC` instance, it returns an `Optional<ABC>`
- `orElseThrow` to get the real `ABC` or raise an exception is no match
- `getText` once to get its text

```
String result = list.stream().filter(p -> p.getId() == n).findFirst().orElseThrow().getText();
```

Answer (score 1):

use `findFirst()` and be aware return type is an **Optional** instance.

```
 String result = list.stream()
                   .filter(p -> p.getId() == n)
                   .map(ABC::getText)
                   .findFirst()
                   .orElse(null);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use *[Stream#findFirst](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/20/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/Stream.html#findFirst())*, with the *[Optional#orElse](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/20/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Optional.html#orElse(T))*.

```java
System.out.println(
    list.stream().filter(abc -> abc.id == n)
                 .map(abc -> abc.text)
                 .findFirst()
                 .orElse(null));
```

Output, where *n* is 3.

```
Rabbit
```